# Is android.os.Build.SERIAL unique for api level 14?

Tags: android

I am developing an application using api 14 (android 4.0).

in manifest:

```
 <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="14" />
```

So in this condition is `android.os.Build.SERIAL` unique in all kinds of android devices (like tablets , phones - with or whthout sim and ...),even for same devices like huawei p8s?

Is it same after factory reset or reboot (unlike Android_ID)?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for [`SERIAL`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html#SERIAL) states:

> A hardware serial number, if available. Alphanumeric only, case-insensitive.

This implies there's a default value if it's not available. This might be `null` or `""` or anything else. In each case it's not unique though.

It also seems that there's no guarantee for uniqueness given. In the end it could be any value. But this value ought to be persistent between reset and reboot.